# Unable to disable right click on images using JQuery

Tags: jquery, right-click

I am trying to disable right click on images using jquery. I have searched and found:

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

but this doesnt work.

However, I tried:

```
$('document').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Which does work, but disables right click on everything.

I then tried `$('document img')` but this does not work either.

Is this no longer possible with new browsers? Does anyone know of a different way to do this?

(PS, running JQuery 1.10.2)

Comment: `$("img").bind()` does work in modern browsers http://jsfiddle.net/aBmLu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the function on the document, and check the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to see what element initiated the event.

I don't recommend disabling this, for this is annoying and really easy to by pass.

Answer (score 1):

For the academics of it:

```
$('#someElement').mousedown(function(event) {
  switch (event.which) {
      case 3:
          event.preventDefault();
          break;
}
});
```

As Itay said, this is annoying and can be easily worked around. I've done it (working around it) many a time, but it can be useful for certain things like custom menus.